# How to load large data in sets in datatable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I'm working on .NET Core framework (C#) and using the DataTable to show my data on the client side. But it's taking too much time to load on the web page. Is there any way to load the data in sets? (I have already searched for the same but didn't get anything.

My action method on Controller where I'm storing the data in view Model (IEnumerable) property

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     _flatInvoiceViewModel.FlatInvoiceModels = _flatInvoiceLogic.GetLatestInvoice(GetRequestDto(string.Empty));
      return View(_flatInvoiceViewModel);
}


this is my view:

``
<table class="table table-bordered mydatatable table-hover nowrap table-sm">


    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th class="mobile tablet desktop">Flat Number</th>
            <th class="mobile tablet desktop">Owner</th>
            <th>Invoice Number</th>
            <th class="mobile tablet desktop">Invoice Date</th>
            <th class="not-mobile">Due Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th class="mobile tablet desktop"> View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="bg-white">
        @foreach (var item in Model.FlatInvoiceModels)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FlatNumber</td>
                <td>@item.AccountName </td>
                <td>@item.DisplayInvoiceNumber</td>
                <td>@item.InvoiceDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</td>
                <td>@item.DueDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</td>
                <td>@item.GrandTotalAmount.ToString("0")</td>
                <td>
                    <a target="_blank" asp-controller="FlatInvoice" asp-action="ShowDetails" asp-route-FlatInvoiceRid="@item.FlatInvoiceRid" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary p-1 mr-0">View</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th class="mobile tablet desktop">Flat Number</th>
            <th class="mobile tablet desktop">Owner</th>
            <th>Invoice Number</th>
            <th class="mobile tablet desktop">Invoice Date</th>
            <th class="not-mobile">Due Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th class="mobile tablet desktop"> View</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/DataTables/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you have a large amount of data coming out from your database then probably you should research how to 'paginate' this data at the database level

Comment: can you clarify what the slow bit is here? what is `GetLatestInvoice`? how long does `GetLatestInvoice` take? how many rows does it return?

Comment: The code you have posted will not be 'slow', unless you have huge amounts of data to display, or the query to the database is complex (or the db server is overloaded).  Please post the query and tell us how many rows you are trying to display.

Comment: I suspect that passing a _string.Empty_ to _GetLatestInvoice(GetRequestDto_ will return all invoices. Not really a good idea, you should have some default that limits the numbers of data to return. It is improbable that your users will find this huge result of any utility